# design/ display user evaluation state's

Tags: page-layout, composition, contrast

Im looking to discuss ideas on how to represent the "evaluation of a user".

- You the evaluator
- Users to be evaluated
- Based on score border around user profile is different color

How could this be represented in 1 single image? 
Attached a Concept wich is not clear enough I need something thats more catchy. [image]

Comment: What kind of evaluation are we talking about?

Comment: @poepje, something like here on stack network, users answer a question and if its good they receive a score if its bad they receive a negative score ( like the yellow and blue green colors )

Comment: Hmm that is a bit of a vague thing.. I would use red for negative and green for good, which is pretty standard (well in most western cultures anyway, there's a question about this, where is said that in China it's the exact opposite :p). If you need more stages in between (for example a rating of 1-10), you could simply use the colours in between. Think of something like `red > red-orange > dark orange > light orange > orange-yellow > yellow > yellow-green > lime> green`

Comment: Your little scrawled human bean is adorable. BTW. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a transparent png icon with a background color applied via CSS?

Images would all be the same size but you could alter colors based on transparent areas of the PNG.

This is a jpg representing the idea....

[image: smilies © 2012]

But the actual png would have the actual icon transparent:

[image: Transparent smile © 2012]

```
<img src="smile.png" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="evaluser0" />
<img src="smile.png" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="evaluser1" />
<img src="smile.png" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="evaluser2" />
<img src="smile.png" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="evaluser3" />

img.evaluser0 { background: #fef200; }
img.evaluser1 { background: #f26422; }
img.evaluser2 { background: #ec145b; }
img.evaluser3 { background: #00a650; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A slide graph with a color scheme progressing from red - green is a good visual progress/success indicator. Numbers are not quite as emotionally powerful but may cross cultural boundaries more easily. Shapes such as checks and pluses are also visual indicators of positive feedback (think facebook like button, or instagram's heart).